# Вредоносный код в joomla

Tags: joomla, javascript, ссылки

Нашлись на сайте трешовые ссылки размещаются в статьях, на страницах не видны, в коде вот такое:

```
<a class="sitelinkx" href="треш" 
title="работу" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: none; 
vertical-align: baseline; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: initial; color: #005689;">
```

Плагин sitelinkx не установлен, в папке с плагинами на сервере его нет, в админке тоже. Поиском через тотал командер не находится ни трешовые ссылки, ни `sitelinkx`.  `Joomla 2.5.`

Что делать-то?

Comment: Т.е. как понимаю там  какие-то рекламные ссылки?

Comment: да, спамные ссылки

Comment: посмотрите, последние плагины, модули что вы устанавливали, по отключайте их и после удаления кеша посмотрите не изчезают ли ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите логи. Посмотрите какие файлы менялись за последнее время. Скорее всего дырка в joomla или плагинов.

Comment: Только так? Логи за 2 года придется смотреть